# Thread blocked when adding elements to HashSet

Tags: java, jpa, wso2, wso2-api-manager, java-threads

I'm using Java EntityManager to work with database in WSO2 AM and the application is working with several threads and sometimes the application is hanging when many requests comes to the application.

The thread dump is as follows,

```
Thread 23217: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.util.HashSet.add(java.lang.Object) @bci=8, line=217 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(java.util.Collection) @bci=29, line=342 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.LinkedHashSet.<init>(java.util.Collection) @bci=22, line=169 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttributes() @bci=13, line=160 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.IdentifiableTypeImpl.initializeIdAttributes() @bci=12, line=95 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.initialize(java.lang.ClassLoader) @bci=251, line=493 (Compiled frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.getMetamodel(java.lang.ClassLoader) @bci=25, line=3476 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.Map) @bci=955, line=754 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession() @bci=54, line=205 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(java.util.Map, javax.persistence.SynchronizationType) @bci=5, line=305 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(java.util.Map, javax.persistence.SynchronizationType) @bci=90, line=337 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager() @bci=3, line=303 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.abc.example.dao.GenericDAO.<init>(com.abc.example..utils.DBProperties) @bci=111, line=35 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.abc.example.dao.NewDAO.<init>(com.abc.example.utils.DBProperties) @bci=2, line=21 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.abc.example.services.MyService.<init>(java.lang.String) @bci=56, line=19 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.abc.example.services.InitService.<init>(com.abc.example.ws.GetRequest) @bci=3, line=17 (Interpreted frame)
 - com.abc.example.ws.MySOAPImpl.getRequest(com.abc.example.ws.GetRequest) @bci=36, line=107 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=40 (Interpreted frame)
 - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=6, line=43 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=57, line=606 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange, java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=57, line=181 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange, java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.util.List) @bci=26, line=97 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange, java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.util.List) @bci=132, line=232 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange, java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.util.List) @bci=76, line=69 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange, java.lang.Object) @bci=215, line=75 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run() @bci=26, line=59 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() @bci=4, line=471 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() @bci=42, line=262 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run() @bci=46, line=126 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) @bci=1, line=37 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(org.apache.cxf.message.Message) @bci=165, line=131 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(org.apache.cxf.message.Message) @bci=137, line=307 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(org.apache.cxf.message.Message) @bci=416, line=121 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(javax.servlet.ServletConfig, javax.servlet.ServletContext, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=102, line=251 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination) @bci=55, line=234 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, boolean) @bci=319, line=208 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=4, line=160 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=42, line=171 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=161, line=293 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=3, line=212 (Interpreted frame)
 - javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) @bci=131, line=755 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=51, line=268 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=446, line=305 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse) @bci=101, line=210 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=783, line=222 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=166, line=123 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=363, line=472 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=148, line=171 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=6, line=99 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=190, line=178 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response, org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve) @bci=3, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response, org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve) @bci=89, line=56 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response, org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve) @bci=26, line=47 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=345, line=141 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=102, line=156 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.ui.valve.XSSValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=116, line=118 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.ui.valve.CSRFValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=17, line=72 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=6, line=936 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=11, line=52 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(org.apache.catalina.connector.Request, org.apache.catalina.connector.Response) @bci=71, line=118 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(org.apache.coyote.Request, org.apache.coyote.Response) @bci=196, line=407 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper) @bci=537, line=1004 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) @bci=158, line=589 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() @bci=129, line=1653 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
```

Even though the HashSet is not thread safe, Many threads(around 100) getting blocked.And all threads have same stack trace in the thread dump. And the server is stuck. In that time, there are many requests coming into the server. For each request, One EntityManager is created.

**EDIT**
The GenericDAO implementation is

```
 Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://"+dbProperties.getHost()+":"+dbProperties.getPort()+"/"+dbProperties.getDbName());
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbProperties.getUser());
  properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbProperties.getPassword());      
  entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDAL", properties).createEntityManager();
```

Comment: are you missing a `commit` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, Nope. commit is there. The problem is happening when creating entityManager with Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewDAL", properties).createEntityManager();

Comment: Show the code for com.abc.example.dao.GenericDAO

Comment: thats not a complete thread dump ... its a stack trace for one thread. If something is blocked then something else is blocking.

Comment: @shazin , I have added the GenericDAO implementation.

Comment: @NeilStockton, Yes it's not the full stack trace. I didn't posted full, since it is too lengthy.

Comment: yes but unless you post the relevant part of WHAT is blocking this thread then not sure how you expect to resolve the issue